# Android ImageView Color Filter for state

Tags: android, imageview, colorfilter

I want to be able to set a color filter to an ImageView depending on it's state.
How can I manage the state of an ImageView (clicked, pressed, enabled)?
any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

```
ImageView iv1;
iv1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_iv1);
iv1.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ImageView 1 is clicked !"
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
iv1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
```